# Proof for the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^0 + x^1 + \dots + x^n)^n$

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> Theorem:
>   The coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^0 + x^1 + \dots + x^n)^n$ is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

How to prove this? Multinomial theorem produces the following
$$ \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k \right)^n
 = \sum_{k_0 + \dots + k_n = n} \binom{n}{k_0, \dots, k_n}
  x^{\sum_{j=0}^{n} j k_j}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=0}^n x^r=\dfrac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

$$\implies(x^0 + x^1 + \dots + x^n)^n=(1-x^{n+1})^n(1-x)^{-n}$$

So, the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^0 + x^1 + \dots + x^n)^n$

$=$ the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x)^{-n}$

Now the $r$th term of $(1-x)^{-n}$ is  $\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)\cdots\{-n-(r-1)\}}{r!}\left(-x\right)^r$

$$=\dfrac{(n+r-1)(n+r-2)\cdots(n+1)n}{r!}x^r$$

Set $r=n$